# Dynamically Adding Tkinter Widgets

Tags: python, tkinter

For my computer science class we have been assigned the task of making a movie kiosk. Users add items to there cart which I store in the form of lists. When the check out screen is loaded I want to added labels displaying which items the user has in their cart. I have the following code:

```
class CheckOut(tk.Frame): #check out page

def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    #create and place base widgets
    backGroundPicture = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Background.jpg"))
    backGroundLabel = tk.Label(self, image=backGroundPicture, borderwidth=0)
    backGroundLabel.image = backGroundPicture
    backGroundLabel.place(x=0, y=0, anchor=tk.NW)

    checkOutLabel = tk.Label(self, text="Check Out", font=("Verdana", 48), bg="#001f33", fg="red")
    checkOutLabel.place(relx=0.5, rely=0, anchor=tk.N)

    returnButton = tk.Button(self, text="Return to Main Menu", bg="#4db8ff", fg="black",
                       command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
    returnButton.place(relx=1, rely=1, anchor=tk.SE)

def update(): #add new widgets displaying items purchase
    print("debug")
    itemLists = []
    for each in movieTitles:
        i = movieTitles.index(each)
        if(adultTickets[i] != 0):
            tempLabel = tk.Label(self, text="Adult Ticket: " + str(adultTickets[i]) + " " + each)
            itemLists.append(tempLabel)
        if(childTickets[i] != 0):
            tempLabel = tk.Label(self, text="Child Ticket: " + str(childTickets[i]) + " " + each)
            itemLists.append(tempLabel)
    for i in itemLists:
        i.place(x=100, y=200, anchor=tk.CENTER)
    print(itemLists)
```

Everything is working except when I try to create the labels with the parent of self, It is undefined. I would like to place them in the same frame that the init method is using. How would I go about getting access to self? Is there some sort of work around I could use?

Comment: Define `update()` with a `self` argument, and call it as an instance method, not a class method.

Comment: you need to fix the indentation of your code. It's not clear if your `update` function is part of the class or not.

Comment: How would I call it as an instance method instead of a class method? I am calling update() from a different class if that affects anything. Indention is correct in my personal code, didn't copy and paste as I expected, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Side note: StackOverflow expects code samples to have an additional 4-space indent. If you simply paste your code, select it in the text box and click the "Code Sample" button in the editor (labelled {}), it will add the indent.

```
class CheckOut(tk.Frame): #check out page
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        #create and place base widgets
        backGroundPicture = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Background.jpg"))
        backGroundLabel = tk.Label(self, image=backGroundPicture, borderwidth=0)
        backGroundLabel.image = backGroundPicture
        backGroundLabel.place(x=0, y=0, anchor=tk.NW)

        checkOutLabel = tk.Label(self, text="Check Out", font=("Verdana", 48), bg="#001f33", fg="red")
        checkOutLabel.place(relx=0.5, rely=0, anchor=tk.N)

        returnButton = tk.Button(self, text="Return to Main Menu", bg="#4db8ff", fg="black",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        returnButton.place(relx=1, rely=1, anchor=tk.SE)

    ...
```

Methods of a class in Python pass the object as the first parameter to the method. As a convention, this parameter is named `self`, but really, you can give it any name.* So add `self` as a parameter to your `update` method. I suppose you also wanted to pass a the movie titles as a parameter to the `update` method.

```
    ...

    def update(self, movieTitles): #add new widgets displaying items purchase
        print("debug")
        itemLists = []
        for each in movieTitles:
            i = movieTitles.index(each)
            if(adultTickets[i] != 0):
                tempLabel = tk.Label(self, text="Adult Ticket: " + str(adultTickets[i]) + " " + each)
                itemLists.append(tempLabel)
            if(childTickets[i] != 0):
                tempLabel = tk.Label(self, text="Child Ticket: " + str(childTickets[i]) + " " + each)
                itemLists.append(tempLabel)
        for i in itemLists:
            i.place(x=100, y=200, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        print(itemLists)
```

This way, after having instantiated your object, you can apply its methods like this:

```
# instantiate object
my_frame = CheckOut(parent, controller)

# apply "update"
my_frame.update(my_movie_titles)

# The previous line has the same effect as this:
CheckOut.update(my_frame, my_movie_titles)
```

Note: I did not test the code, I just fixed the little syntax mistakes you had in there. At a glance, it seems like the labels for the movies will all have the same position.

Also, as user "zondo" suggests, lambdas here and there clutter the code; getting rid of them can make the code easier to read. A simple occurrence like this can be replaced with the function `partial` from the `functools` module:

```
from functools import partial

returnButton = tk.Button(self, ..., 
    command=partial(controller.show_frame, StartPage))
```

- Other languages such as C++/Java and family will reserve a keyword instead. (`this`)